# Istio instead of nxing proxy_pass

Tags: kubernetes, networking, proxy, istio, nginx-ingress

I'm looking for a way to use Istio as a replacement for nginx with proxy_pass. I'm unable to find anything reasonable online. I've only found this [bit](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2019/proxy), but this setup doesn't work if I configure my device to use istio gateway as a proxy (it works if I spoof dns on the device to think edition.cnn.com ip address is istios ip address). But I still have an issue with many different things (css\javascript\etc) being downloaded directly from the web bypassing istio.

Something like [this](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/9170), however I have very little understanding if its possible to do at all with Istio. I could reproduce filter part with `envoyfilter`, I'm not sure about clusters? a `serviceentry` should be a cluster, but I don't think it accepts* variables?

My attempt so far:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: yandex
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 36003
      name: TCP
      protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: yandex
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - '*.yandex.ru'
  - yandex.ru
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: tls
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: yandex
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - '*.yandex.ru'
  - yandex.ru
  gateways:
  - yandex
  tls:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - yandex
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 443
```

edit: Using AKS 1.19.13 and Istio 1.11.2
edit: here's the config I'm trying to replace

```
    user nobody nogroup;
    worker_processes auto;
    events { }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    http {
      # The format below needs to match the format defined in the start.sh file
      log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '$scheme $host "$request" $request_time $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$http_user_agent"';
      
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;
      server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    
      server {
        gzip on;
        # if we do not match either of the below - reject the request
        if ($http_host ~ "^((?!(domain1|domain2)).)*$")  {
          return 403;
          break;
        }
    
        listen {{ .Values.service.port }} ;
        server_name ~.+;
        proxy_connect;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://$http_host;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: added this information to the question

Comment: Please clarify your problem. I would appreciate a reproducible example of the request, expected and actual result. Could you provide the nginx solution as an example of the desired configuration? Do you mean nginx-ingress or just nginx pod  and what is source and the destination of the request?

Comment: did you take a look at the provided code? it kinda specifies all of that. however, I've attached the sample nginx configuration (I didn't initially, because people who work with istio might not understand nginx configuration).

Comment: I read your question carefully several times :) But I have still a few questions. How we should route the pod's traffic to nginx? Do we have to use HTTP_PROXY variable or firewall rules to intercept the traffic and redirect it to the nginx proxy? Additionally please answer all my previous answer to make your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Did you see [this problem](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23298)? It is described how to use Istio as a reverse proxy (similar to nginx proxy_pass). It is helpful for you?

Comment: I've seen the article you are linking and it doesn't solve the issue at all. they use squid as a proxy, whereas I'm looking for a way to do the same, but without squid, nginx or any other solution. other questions you are asking are irrelevant. what I'm looking to do - is accept traffic on istio ingress pods and act like a proxy, similar to [this](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/9170) envoy configuration.

Comment: The questions I asked are important. I am trying to recreate your problem and propose a solution, however I need to have the exact guidelines I asked for.

Comment: I'm thankful for your time, however I don't see why would you care how traffic gets to the  ingress? anyhow, the flow is as follows: smartphone initiates a connection to website.com, but it has a proxy configured in its settings such as that all traffic is being redirected to istio ingress, when istio ingress receives traffic to website.com from any one it should act as a `proxy_pass` and serve the request, if, however, client asks for domain.com it shouldn't respond to such a request. all of the clients of this `proxy` would be external to the client and 101% irrelevant in this question

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use additional tools? I found another very [similar thread](https://discuss.istio.io/t/is-it-possible-to-use-istio-as-a-reverse-proxy-similar-to-nginx-proxy-pass/6319), is it helpful? You can also ask your question at discuss.istio.io

Comment: i can (I use nginx with the config captured in the question now), but I'm exploring ways to do this without nginx only using istio\envoy :) I think I saw that thread and it suffers from the same issue. it would not work like a `proxy_pass` and i'd need to know where all css\js\etc is loaded from

Comment: I have found [this similar topic](https://discuss.istio.io/t/routing-directly-from-ingress-gateway-to-an-external-service-via-egress-gateway/6670) Could it be helpful?

Comment: this is an interesting option, however, i need to proxy anything under particular domain (including subdomains). so this would work for a single domain, but how do I use this to do that? :(

Comment: Is your problem still unresolved? Did you try to ask your question on the dedicated [istio site](https://discuss.istio.io/)?